# @mention approver in Teams pipeline notification

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Does anyone know how to make approver names tags, instead of plain text? Is this possible?

For example, here's a sample MS Teams notification similar to what we receive. Notice how the approver listed, Kyle Roger, is listed in plain text? I would like for that name to be @mention'd so that the approver's attention gets brought to the channel. The channel in which we receive these release pipeline notifications are pretty much ignored until a problem needs to get investigated.

I realize that you can also get emails about the pending approval, but that's not a preferred option for our use case.[image: Pending approval notification example]

What I've been working on is a Power Automate solution where a flow would look for keywords in Teams notifications, extract the list of approvers, then reply to the same parent message with the approvers @mention'd. But it seems like a clunky workaround so I was hoping there was a more direct way of getting approvers' attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that the Azure Pipeline App in teams doesn't support showing @mention information.

It can only show the plain text for the time being. And it does not support modifying the format of notification cards in teams.

Currently, the easiest way to remind users remains the automated email when approval is pending.

Other than that, other methods will be more complicated.

In addition to using Power Automate, you can also consider using service hooks to send requests to other app services to handle the requests and alert the users.

For example:

[image]

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.